# using \visible without beamer.cls

Tags: presentations

Is it possible to use `\visible` without the beamer.cls?
Or the other way around: I would like to try to build my own presentation
class (very simple, it might be a kind of LaTeX exercise) but I have no clue
how to incorporate something like `\visible`, `\only`, `\pause` and so on.

NB: I know ppower4 but I do not want to use postprocessing.

Comment: All those commands are defined in beamer not in latex, in principle of course beamer is open source and you could find the code and try to extract it but the overlay mechanism permeates the whole code, it would be a massive job.  it would probably be as easy to write from scratch as to extract from the beamer codebase.

Comment: I was afraid that something like this would be the answer. Do you can tell me a starting point as I do not have the faintest clue how to do this?

Comment: [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is intricate, to say the least. Commands like `\visible`-and-friends work on the principle that the entire `frame` content is read, then reset a number of times, depending on how many slides should be produced from a single `frame`.

Comment: @Werner: `intricate` is understatement ;-)